# Horizontal form form-inline in bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I have the following HTML using bootstrap:

```
<form class="form-inline">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputAmount">Amount (in dollars)</label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputAmount" placeholder="Amount" readonly="readonly" value="Have a ">
        <select>
          <option value="adventure">adventure</option>
          <option value="break">break</option>                                    
      </select>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputAmount" placeholder="Amount" readonly="readonly" value=" , have a ">
        <select>
          <option value="kitkat">kitkat</option>
          <option value="twix">twix</option>
        </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Go!</button>
</form>
```

Ideally what I'm trying to achieve is for everything to read:

> "Have a break, have a kitkat"

Where the user can form a sentence according to select options and press go.

I can't seem to make them appear horizontally and intuitive. What am I doing wrong?

Are there any other controls which would appear better for this?

Comment: Do you have a visual example ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consult the [Bootstrap documentation on inline forms](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-inline).

```
<form class="form-inline">
  <div class="form-group">
    Have a
    <select class="form-control"><option>Break</option></select>
    Have a
    <select class="form-control"><option>Kit kat</option></select>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Go</button>
</form>
```

[Example Bootstrap fiddle](http://www.bootply.com/wfT7MKH4bQ)